# отправка формы через jquery с переходом на 2 разные страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-form

Я сделал доп. поле в форме заказа на лэндинге. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы если жмут кнопку "отправить\заказать" при учете, что это доп. поле заполнено, то  переносило на 1 страничку, а если не заполнено, то на другую?

Хочу чтобы, если поле "Промокод" пустое, то перенаправляло на 1 страницу, а если с правильным значением, то на другую.

Форма:

```
{{form1Begin action="/success.html" alias="item" class="m1-form" validationByAlert="1"}}


        {{form1Field name="fio" type="text" required="1" validator="~^.+$~" class="field" placeholder="Введите ваше имя"}}
        {{form1Error name="fio" text="Поле «Ф.И.О» заполнено неверно" class="error" style="color: red"}}

        {{form1Field name="phone" type="text" required="1" validator="~\+?\d~" class="field" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон"}}
        {{form1Error name="phone" text="Поле «Телефон» заполнено неверно" style="color: red"}}

        {{form1Field name="additional11" type="text" required="1" pattern="BONUS" class="field" placeholder="Введите промокод"}}
        {{form1Error name="additional11" text="Промокод введен неверно" style="color: red"}}

            <button class="button-m" type="submit">Оформить заказ</button>
{{form1End}}
```

Comment: Приведите код. А так: почему бы и нет, превентите сабмит, смотрите что в инпуте, относительно того каково его значение определяете урл запроса.

Comment: @MedvedevDev плохо разбираюсь во всем этом, только учусь, подскажите пожалуйста, как перенаправить в данном случае к примеру на страницу "/success2.html" если поле промокод пустое, а если заполнено то на  "/success.html" или наоборот, не принципиально.

Answer (score 0):

Частный случай, сложно привести что-то более точное с имеющимися вводными.

```js
$(() => {
  const $form = $('#form');
  const $promo = $('#form').find('[name=additional11]');
  const onSubmit = e => {
    // Отменяем отправку формы
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // Просто вывод адреса на который будет отправленная форма в зависимости от того пустое поле [name=additional11] или нет
    console.log($promo.val().length > 0 ? '/promo.php' : '/success.html');
    
    // Раскомментировать. Назначает адрес куда будет отправлена форма. Если в поле есть хоть что-то, то посылаем на некий обработчик (в данном примере promo.php) иначе success.html
    // $form.attr('action', $promo.val().length > 0 ? '/promo.php' : '/success.html');
    
    // Отключает слушатель, что бы отправка не зациклилась
    $form.off('submit',onSubmit);
    
    // Раскомментировать. Отправка формы (после назначения нужного пути)
    // $form.submit();
    
    // Снова назначает слушатель
    $form.on('submit',onSubmit);
  };
  
  // Навешиваем слушатель на отправку формы
  $form.on('submit',onSubmit);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="form">
  <input type="text" name="fio" placeholder="Введите ваше имя">
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон">
  <input type="text" name="additional11" placeholder="Введите промокод">
  <button class="button-m" type="submit">Оформить заказ</button>
</form>
```